# Отображение запрашиваемых данных из разных *.cs файлов

Tags: c#

Есть два *.cs файла. Один из них Program.cs, другой filereader.cs
Как отобразить требуемое, будучи это строка или перменная?

*Program.cs*:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] file1 = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test2.txt");
            foreach(var line1 in file1)
            {

            }
            string string1 = "123abc";
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

*filereader.cs*:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    public class filreader
    {
        public static void main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(тут отобразить line1);
            Console.WriteLine(тут отобразить string1);

        }
    }
}
```

P.S. Еще одну вещь хотел узнать..как использовать в filereader.cs line1, которая в foreach находиться ?

Comment: В Program создать экземпляр класса fileReader, пробросить в него параметры, вызывать. А с чем у вас затруднения? Преподаватель разве не объяснял, что такое параметры функции?

Comment: @AK трудности в "создать экземпляр класса fileReader, пробросить в него параметры, вызывать". А причем тут преподаватель ?

Comment: Ну а где вы это ваше задание взяли? Изучаете c# самостоятельно по книгам? Ну допустим, не преподаватель. А какую книгу вы читаете и какие разделы до этого успели посмотреть в книге? Может тогда двигаться поступательно по темам - от простых к сложным?

Comment: @AK сам тестирую разное, ну да, от простого к сложному, а как иначе ?

Comment: Не использовать слова "пробросить" и "текстирую", смысл которых известен только тем, кто их употребляет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вероятно вы хотите что-то типа такого. Класс Program вида:

```
string[] file1 = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test2.txt");
string string1 = "123abc";
foreach (var line1 in file1)
{
    FileDisplayer.Execute(line1, string1);
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

А второй класс - такой:

```
public static class FileDisplayer
{
    public static void Execute(string param1, string param2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(param1);
        Console.WriteLine(param2);
    }
}
```

Тут нужно пояснить две вещи.

Во-первых, класс 2 сделан статическим, чаще на практике делают обычные классы, создавая экземпляр:

```
string[] file1 = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test2.txt");
string string1 = "123abc";
var displayer = new FileDisplayer();
foreach (var line1 in file1)
{
    displayer.Execute(line1, string1);
}
Console.ReadKey();

public class FileDisplayer
{
    public void Execute(string param1, string param2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(param1);
        Console.WriteLine(param2);
    }
}
```

(Подробнее почитайте хотя бы здесь: https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.1.php )

Сделал класс статическим, т.к. ничего по сути не содержит как и системный Console, по факту его расширяющий.

Во-вторых, строка с определением string1 перенесена ДО цикла, иначе невозможно использовать: либо делаете метод Execute принимающий один параметр, либо делаете два параметра (как вы привели код), но тогда переменная должна быть известна до вызова